# how to create a setTimeout in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve a timeout feature for my app.

my `setTimsout` codes don't seem to work. It output `'call here`' in my console right away instead of waiting for 3 second.

Can anyone give me a hint for why this is happening? thanks!

```
main.prototype.init = function(){
     var instance = this;
     $('.test').each(function(){
               //codes…..
                  window.setTimeout(instance.playAnimation(this), 3000)                    
      });
}

main.prototype.play = function(item){
     console.log('call here')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you aren't passing a function to `setTimeout`, but the result of executing `playAnimation`. Try this:

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    instance.playAnimation(_this);
}, 3000);
```

Note that I saved off the value of `this`, since `this` inside your `setTimeout` function will refer to the `window`, not the `.test` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){instance.playAnimation(this);}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass function to setTimeout, try this

setTimeout(function(){instance.playAnimation(this)},3000);